# How to process error when loading NetworkImage?

Tags: flutter

How to process error when loading NetworkImage? And more likely to load another image (from assets for example) it this case.

```
child: Image(
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    width: 120,
    image: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
),
```

Comment: take a look https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/cached-images

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html check `errorBuilder`

Comment: what does `fit` property have to do with error handling?

Comment: @pskink Image.network is a solution

Comment: you can use `Image` too - it also has `errorBuilder`, but `Image.network` is easier to use

Comment: @pskink why `Image` is harder to use?

Comment: because you have to use `NetworkImage(imageUrl)` instead of simple string `imageUrl`

Comment: @pskink Image.network implementation took a llitle bitt less lines of code :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) image widget for
error image as well as show local image for loading time.

```
    CachedNetworkImage( 
    imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150", 
placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(),
 errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Image.asset('assets/image.png')
 ),
```